# Continuous function on a segment

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [a , b] \rightarrow [a ,b]$ , and $f$ is continuous over $[a,b].$ Show that there is a $k  \in [a , b] $ such that $f(k) = k.$   Is this it unique ?

Comment: consider http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B+2x+abs+sin%2835x%29%2C+x%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $g(x):= f(x)-x$. Note that $g(a)=f(a)-a\geq 0$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b\leq 0$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: It sounds like Intermediate value theoreme :-) . thanks .

of course the uniqueness of $~k~~$ depends on wether $~f~$ is monotonous or not .

Comment: You're welcome. Also you have the right idea about uniqueness, but be careful: there are non-monotone $f$ for which $k$ is unique and vice-versa.  The big point here is that the IVT does not give any idea of the number of roots so we cannot deduce uniqueness. You can write down counterexamples quite quickly.